# `cabal-install` refuses to solve conflicting `ghc` and `containers` versions

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, cabal-install, conflicting-libraries

[This repository](https://github.com/sgraf812/ghc-containers-conflict) contains a reproduction for an annoying error I got while using `doctest` in a test-suite.

`cabal-install`s solver fails to find a solution for this `build-depends` field using GHC 8.0.2:

```
build-depends:       
    base >= 4.7 && < 5
  , doctest == 0.11.4
  , containers == 0.5.10.2
```

Note that `doctest` depends transitively depends on `ghc-8.0.2`, which itself depends on `containers-0.5.7.1`, conflicting with my own constraints.
That's basically what `cabal install` is trying to tell me:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: containers (dependency of repro-0.1.0.0)
rejecting: containers-0.5.7.1/installed-0.5... (conflict: repro =>
containers==0.5.10.2)
trying: containers-0.5.10.2
next goal: doctest (dependency of repro-0.1.0.0)
rejecting: doctest-0.13.0, doctest-0.12.0 (conflict: repro => doctest==0.11.4)
trying: doctest-0.11.4
next goal: ghc (dependency of doctest-0.11.4)
rejecting: ghc-8.0.2/installed-8.0... (conflict: containers==0.5.10.2, ghc =>
containers==0.5.7.1/installed-0.5...)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

Now, what bugs me is that `stack install` works just fine using [`lts-9` and an `extra-deps` for the containers version](https://github.com/sgraf812/ghc-containers-conflict/blob/0b10e5f390d0e228e6c2c708f6961ebff76b2edc/stack.yaml).
So in theory, `cabal-install` could also do 'the right thing' here. How can I tell it to?

Comment: I have no idea why it works in Stack. The `ghc` package actually exports some functions that take or give types defined in `containers`, so the difficulty is not just administrative.

Comment: Actually I have a test suite in my project that depends on both `containers >= 0.5.9.2` and `ghc` and `stack` builds it just fine with lts-9, which is based on `ghc-8.0.2`. As long as I don't mix up data types and functions from `containers`, of course (in which case the compiler complains). So, this works fine for my use case and I'm glad it does.